# How to add a property to an interface with indexable types

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an interface which is declare this way:

```
export interface ITvChannelState {
  [key: string]: IChannel;
}
```

I want it to look like this:

```
export interface ITvChannelState {
  [key: string]: IChannel;
  isLoaded: boolean;
}
```

The reason it look like this is my state is build based on a serverResponse which return an array Of TvChannel. Channel are not clearly defined so i can't use a string literal or enum to list them the server can return new channel and I want them to be properly typed. I also want the state to contain other property which aren't compute property.

Here the error generated by typescript when using the syntaxt provided in the second code snippet:

> Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'IChannel'
>
> tv-channel.d.ts(4, 3): The expected type comes from this index signature.

Comment: if you have indexable type all of other property has to be same type (or extendable of this type) so something like this: export interface ITvChannelState {
  [key: string]: IChannel | boolean;
  isLoaded: boolean;
}